# How to set OFFSET if there is a chance that new columns are added in between

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I have a scenario where in based on a button searck(click) I need to update one particular cell with value from search result.
The search button TopLeftCell property and OFFSET() method is used to get to the cell to which the value is copied

```
With Sheets("Test").Shapes("btnSearch").TopLeftCell

  .Offset(0, -4).Value = searchResult

End With
```

But there is a requirement that if there is any columns that was added to later between these cells then offset will have to be changed back again

Is there any way to handle this case so that we don't have to worry about the OFFSET method even when we add/delete a column in between

Please note that these cells are actually part of a list/grid in excel which are dynamically incremented.

Comment: will the column that needs to be searched have some type of heading or identifier in any row that will remain unchanged? Meaning, the column number itself may change but the defined heading will always be in row `n`?

Comment: Yes, it has heading which will not be changed

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this and it worked:

```
With Sheets("Test")

    Dim resCol As Long
    'change myHeader to defined header and row number as needed
    resCol = .Rows(1).Find("myHeader").Column 

    Dim resRow As Long
    resRow = .Shapes("btnSearch").TopLeftCell.Row

    .Cells(resRow, resCol).Value = searchResult

End With
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. there is one problem here that my header is multi lined and it cant be changed to single line.

Comment: @user3428508 - I suggest adjusting this code to make it fit that. If you had stated that originally, I would have created code to do that. The concept I provided will still work if you make the adjustment to find the correct header column based on your data format.